# Java SWT table columns remove

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm working on GUI with SWT and I'm trying to clear all table contents and columns (make it fully empty)
I've used the command `.removeAll()` but the columns still there but empty.
How can I remove/delete columns too?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `getItemCount()` return after you have called `removeAll()`?

Comment: `getItemCount()` returns 0

Comment: So `removeAll` has done what it is supposed to do and removed everything. What is it that you think is wrong? If you are expecting the table to change size or something like that you need to redo the layout.

Comment: I'll set width to 0 if so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information, `.removeAll` is used to remove all the elements from a list that are contained in the specified collection.

You can use the `.clear` and `SetVisible(bool visible)` to make the contents empty and invisible from the interface.

For the example,

```
txtName.clear();
txtName.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using `removeAll()` to remove all items from the table. If you also need to start from scratch with an empty table (ie. remove the columns) you can simply dispose the columns with the `dispose()` method:

```
for (final TableColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
    column.dispose();
}
```

That being said, if you really need to completely change the content of a `Table` to the point where the columns are all different, you may as well simply dispose and re-create the whole table.